# Django 2/3 only one post_save generated celery signal received each time model is saved

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I use multiple post_save functions to trigger different celery (4.4.0, 4.8.3) tasks and tried Django 2 and 3. For some strange reason celery stopped executing all tasks in parallel instead only one task gets received each time model is saved. The other tasks are not even received.

To run all the tasks, I have to save the model multiple times. It was working before and I have no idea why the behavior changed all of a sudden.

I am starting the queue with:

```
celery -A appname worker -l info -E
```

My post save functions:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=RawFile)
def execute_rawtools_qc(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    rawtools_qc.delay(instance.path, instance.path)

@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=RawFile)
def execute_rawtools_metrics(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    rawtools_metrics.delay(instance.abs_path, instance.path)
```

And my tasks:

```
@shared_task
def rawtools_metrics(raw, output_dir):
    cmd = rawtools_metrics_cmd(raw=raw, output_dir=output_dir)
    os.system(cmd)

@shared_task    
def rawtools_qc(input_dir, output_dir):
    cmd = rawtools_qc_cmd(input_dir=input_dir, output_dir=output_dir)
    os.system(cmd)
```

Before those tasks where executed in parallel as soon as the model was saved. Now, the first task gets executed when the model instance is saved, and the second instance is executed the second time the model is saved. And then the functions alternate each time. Any idea what may cause this strange behavior?

UPDATE: I think both task are executed randomly, but only one for each save.

Also, there are no other celery workers running.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running both functions for the same model run them in the same post_save method:

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=RawFile)
def execute_rawtools_qc(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    rawtools_qc.delay(instance.path, instance.path)
    rawtools_metrics.delay(instance.abs_path, instance.path)
```

Comment: Also, I tried that but the problem stays the same. Therefore, I think it is a celery problem.

Comment: can you check the celery master to claim your comment? contributions welcome